# Python/Django - Connecting to a legacy SQL Server Databse getting error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sqlserver_ado'"

Tags: python, sql-server, django, pywin32, django-mssql

So I'm connecting my Django app to a SQL server database using  django-mssql and pywin32-218.win-amd64-py2.7

Everything works great if I'm starting from scratch by creating models and syncing the database.

However, I'd like to connect to an existing SQL Server DB. I followed [these instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/)

And ended up with the following model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Payload(models.Model):
id = models.sqlserver_ado.fields.BigAutoField(db_column='Id') # Field name made lowercase.
code = models.CharField(db_column='Code', max_length=10) # Field name made lowercase.
body = models.TextField(db_column='Body') # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Payload'
```

If I try to run 'runserver' I get the following error:

**File "C:\Users\luke\PycharmProjects\project\API\models.py", line 7, in Payload
    id = models.sqlserver_ado.fields.BigAutoField(db_column='Id') # Field name made lowercase.
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sqlserver_ado'**

However, If I comment out the line "**id = models.sqlserver_ado.fields.BigAutoField(db_column='Id') # Field name made lowercase.**"

Everything fires up perfectly.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having **sqlserver_ado** installed. Import *BigAutoField* like this:

```
from sqlserver_ado.fields import BigAutoField
```

Then replace `id = models.sqlserver_ado.fields.BigAutoField(db_column='Id') # Field name made lowercase` with

```
id = BigAutoField(db_column='Id') # Field name made lowercase.
```